# Combine two dictionaries based on value of 1st and key of 2nd

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following two dictionaries:

```
{1: ['1'], 2: ['1'], 3: ['1'], 4: ['2'], 5: ['1']}
```

```
{1: ['2|N|'], 2: ['1|N|']}
```

I want to take the key of dictionary 2 and link it with the value's of dictionary 1, for a desired output of the following:

```
{1: ['2|N|'], 2: ['2|N|'], 3: ['2|N|'], 4: ['1|N|'], 5: ['2|N|']}
```

Basically combining the key, value of dictionary 2 on the value of dictionary 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward solution:

```
adict = {1: ['1'], 2: ['1'], 3: ['1'], 4: ['2'], 5: ['1']}
mapping = {1: ['2|N|'], 2: ['1|N|']}
    
for key, value in adict.items():
    adict[key] = [mapping[int(k)][0] for k in value]

print(adict)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: ['2|N|'], 2: ['2|N|'], 3: ['2|N|'], 4: ['1|N|'], 5: ['2|N|']}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is dict comprehension manner of it

```
{k:b[int(v[0])]  for k,v in a.items() }
```

```
{1: ['2|N|'], 2: ['2|N|'], 3: ['2|N|'], 4: ['1|N|'], 5: ['2|N|']}
```